# Webstorm debugging?

Tags: debugging, webstorm

I recently installed Webstorm for my html5 / css / javascript project. I have been unable to run or debug sucessfully from inside the IDE. I have a typical web setup with and index.html file and css and js folders. I'm using MAMP for my local web server and it starts and runs my site  no problem when run inside my browser. I can't run because the "Run" button is greyed out. When I try to debug (I set a breakppint in a js file that I know should execute up front) Firefox opens but just shows (http://) with no full path to my index.html AND I see a message in the IDE:    Remote URL isn't specified for 'kazaam_localDB.js' so breakpoints won't work in it. Set remote URL for 'kazaam_localDB.js

I did configure my local server when I created a "new project from existing files". I did notice the  first time I did try to debug a message cam up saying it needed to configure Firefox with an add-on or extension, but I'm not sure that succeeded because I can't debug...

Comment: Ok I stopped Firefox THEN retried debugger from webstorm and now I can debug. I also see now the extension has been installed in Firefox.   BUT I still cannot stop at my set breakpoint and receive message:   ""Remote URL isn't specified for 'kazaam_localDB.js' so  breakpoints won't work in it. Set remote URL for 'kazaam_localDB.js".   Any one have any ideas on how to resolve?

Comment: A very detailed article for configuring Webstorm for Javascript debugging : http://www.gamefromscratch.com/post/2012/08/17/Debugging-with-JavaScript-with-WebStorm.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Ok here is what you have to do:

Ok stop and exit  Firefox THEN retry debugger from webstorm.  You should now see now the extension has been installed in Firefox.

When you set breakpoint in js file in a local file WebStorm it needs to know which URL corresponds to that file on the server. To specify URL mapping for local files you can either click on 'Set remote url' link in the warning popup or open Run | 'Edit Configurations' dialog and select the run configuration under 'JavaScript Debug' node.